# Selenium Firefox Browser has no internet connection

Tags: selenium, firefox, automated-tests

Selenium Firefox Browser has no internet connection :- when i try to run my selenium script using firefox , I get no internet connection error where as i do have good internet connection. Can anyone help?Thanks in advance

Here is the code, Its a dataprovider code to be able to create the data driven tests. But everytime i run this whether on firefox or be it chrome its not working

```
public class Test2 {
                //webdriver object
                WebDriver driver;
                //test annotation       
                @Test(dataProvider="wordpressdata")
                public void loginTest(String Username, String Password) throws InterruptedException{

     //Setting the system property to use chrome exe            

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Downloads\\Softwares\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe" );
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-login.php");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_login")).sendKeys(Username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("user_pass")).sendKeys(Password);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wp-submit']")).click();
        }

          //this is after method for driver quit      
        @AfterMethod
        public void teardown(){
        driver.quit();
        }
         //this is data provider       
        @DataProvider(name="wordpressdata")
        public Object[][] passdata(){
        Object[][] data = new Object[3][2];
        data[0][0] = "Admin";
        data[0][1] = "demo123";
        data[1][0] = "Admin";
        data[1][1] = "demo23";
        data[2][0] = "Admin";
        data[2][1] = "demo14";
        return data;
         }    
         }
```

This code is not letting me open it in either Firefox browser or Chrome.

Comment: Are you getting this problem only in case of Firefox? Your code works well for other browsers? Also attach screenshot of error message.

Comment: The Exact error is "unable to connect"

Comment: I tried its not working in chrome as well

Comment: Copy paste your code also in your question

Comment: Copy pasted the code ... though i dont see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Could you copy paste the complete error message that you are getting

Comment: Its working fine now , Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: How it got resolved? What changes you did?